# Best way to create a file and then use the data later

Tags: java

Java: Best way to store data in a file.
I am doing a comparison between 2 versions of a file and then record the differences between the file as Insert, Deleted or Changed. The data needs to be logged in a similiar format >>

```
Version_old=1.28 Version_new=1.29
Operation=Changed,SourceLineFrom=55,SourceLineTo=55 TargetFileFrom=55 TargetFileTo= 55
Operation=Delete, SourceLineFrom=57,SourceLineTo=59 TargetFilefrom=57 TargetFileTo= -
```

The data is needed later on. Can anyone suggest me which is the best and easiest format to save this data? the data have to retrieved later on for processing.

Comment: I would use a multi-line format. This will make taking the difference easier for existing tools.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, i am not using any tools.. i have to highlight the file with colors based on the operation... so basically need to read the line no: based on the operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

too amny options to really be helpful.

it sounds like maybe XML - at least you get free parsers.

Comment: wha i was doing till now was appending all the data to a stringbuffer and writing it to a file. String str= new String ("<**OP=INS**"+" **SOURCE_LINE_FROM="+"-"+"**"+" **SOURCE_LINE_TO"+"-"+"**"+" **TARGET_LINE_FROM="+printnewline+"**"+" **TARGET_LINE_TO="+(printnewline+lines-1)+"**"+" **LINES"+lines+"**");
sb.append(str);

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the format produced by git diff tool. It's clear, can easily be parsed, and I'm sure that there are existing parsers for it

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to store the data using JSON format. This is mainly possible because each change set is constructed as a name-value pair (a Map basically).

Comment: have you come across any examples demonstrating JSON format?? i'm relatively new to java programming.